# While loop - Beginner

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am a beginner in C (and programming) and I found mylsef with this problem.

The code compile, but it return to me until number 11. I set the "While loop" to stop when is "<= 10". So doesn't make much sense to me.

thanks in advance =).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    int n;

    n = 0;


    while (n <= 10) {
    n++;
    printf("%i\n", n);

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: you incremented 'n' before printing. So it returns up to 11. whats the confusion?

Comment: If you're expecting "10" to be the last thing printed, you'd want to use `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: You first increment the variable n before printing it. Therefore in the last loop with n == 10 the variable n is incremented by 1 which is 11 and then printed as n == 11.

Comment: Oww!! That's it, noobie mistake. =) thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

When `n` equals 10, `n <= 10` is true, then `n++;` will increase `n` by 1, and that `printf()` will print 11; after that, `n <= 10` will fail, and the `while` loop finish.

Comment: Thanks! =) 
Your answer was precise =)

Answer (score 1):

The basic behavior of the while loop is:

1. Check the condition.
2. If it's false, stop.
3. Otherwise, execute the whole body of the loop.
4. Go back to 1.

In other words, it does not stop the instant the condition becomes false, but only after the body finishes executing. So in this case, when n = 10, `n<=10` is true, the loop body executes, which first increments `n` to 11. The loop execution does not stop here, event though `n<=10` is now false. Rather, it continues to the `printf`  call, which prints out 11. Now that the loop body is finished, the condition is checked again, and as it is false the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set n to 0 and you iterate until 10 in your while loop, the loop iterates 11 times. Try n < 10!

Answer (score 1):

Because you said while (n <= 10) to increment.

When n becomes 10, it checks itself against your condition. Is 10 less than or equal to 10? yes it is equal to 10, so enter the loop, and increment 10 by 1 and print.

It isn't until n becomes 11 on this next pass that it won't satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
n=0;

while(n<=10) { printf("%i\n", n); n++; }
```

Comment: and if you don't want to print 0 then init n with 1, example n=1;

Answer (score 0):

You first increment the variable n before printing it. Therefore in the last loop with n == 10 the variable n is incremented by 1 which is 11 and then printed as n == 11.

You should increment n after printing it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    int n;
    n = 0;

    while (n <= 10){
       printf("%i\n", n);
       n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last iteration of the loop (ie, n=10) looping condition satisfies and control enters the loop. In the loop body, first n++ is executed making it 11. Then printf() is executed, printing the value 11.

If you want to print from 1 to 10, then initialize n=1 and do n++ after the printf().

```
int n=1;
while( n <= 10 ) {
    printf( "%d\n", n );
    n++;
}
```